# HTML table with random background

Tags: html, css, html-table

How  can I  make  a random background when `HTML page` loads?

I have one table in HTML page, and I use this line of HTML code for make `background` for a `Table`.

```
<table background="image/1.jpg">
```

In `Image folder` I have 5 images, and I want to change the background randomly on every HTML page load.

Comment: Do you use any server-side technologies? (ASP, PHP, Java, Ruby, Perl, Python...)

Comment: @adarshr, no. that is an simple `HTML` webpage.

Comment: if you have at least Apache running, follow my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make an array of images and set it onload function of page refer [example](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-79591.html)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using Apache alone. No scripting (client/server-side) required at all.

For this however, you should be able to modify your Apache configuration to allow URL Rewrites and Rewrite Maps. Refer to the [instructions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/rewritemap.html) for help on how to do this.

Once you've done the initial configuration, all you have to do is define a map (images.txt) of all the image suffixes (1, 2, 3...). Then you configure apache to pick up the URL `/images/random.jpg` and randomly substitute it with URLs such as `/images/image_1.jpg` and `/images/image_3.jpg`.

The below lines can go to your `httpd.conf` or you can put the second line alone inside the `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteMap images rnd:/path/to/images.txt
RewriteRule ^/(.*)images/random.jpg /images/image_${images:dynamic}.jpg
```

**Note:** The `RewriteMap` definition cannot be used inside `.htaccess`. But you are free to use the `RewriteRule` directive in both `.htaccess` and the main configuration.

Content of the map. Place `images.txt` in the path defined in the `RewriteMap` directive above.

```
## images.txt

dynamic 1|2|3|4|5
```

Of course, you'll have to change your HTML to:

```
<table background="/images/random.jpg">
```

This way of picking up such random images is very clean compared to the scripting solutions. The only drawback I see is being able to access the main Apache configuration (`httpd.conf`, virtual host configuration) in order to place the map definition there. Many shared hosting companies place restrictions on doing that. If you can get past that hurdle, it's really a cake walk.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP:

```
$images = array();

if ($dir = opendir("your/image/folder"))
{
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
    {
        if (preg_match('~(png)|(gif)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(bmp)~', $file) > 0) // Use this to filter just images you want
        {
            $images[] = $file;
        }
    }
}

echo '<table background="image/' . $images[mt_rand(0, (count($images) - 1))] . '">';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some [jQuery](http://jquery.org/) plugins:

- [Random Image jQuery Plugin](http://www.robwalshonline.com/posts/jquery-plugin-random-image-on-page-load/)
- [Easy jQuery Image Rotator](http://www.alohatechsupport.net/webdesignmaui/maui-web-site-design/easy_jquery_auto_image_rotator)

Answer (score 1):

You could use javascript. Use Math.random() function and make it return a number between 1 and 5. Then just change the background of the table to the number that the function gave you.
I don't know how u should do it in html.

Hope this helpes you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As adarshr pointed out in his comment, it may probably be easier to deal with it server-side.

Yet, if you want to do it on the client-side, you can try this kind of javascript:

```
window.onload=function(){  
   var thediv=document.getElementById("yourid");  
   var imgarray = new Array("imageone.gif", "imagetwo.gif", imagethree.gif");  
   var spot =Math.floor(Math.random()* imgarry.length);  
   thediv.style.background="url("+imgarray[spot]+")";  
}
```

Here is [another example](http://www.blogfodder.co.uk/2008/1/1/javascript-css-random-background-image) from a blog post